# Why can't I change the content of the div?

Tags: jquery, html

Good day, my problem here is that I can't change the content of div of **EmployeeInformation.html** while I am in the MainScreen.html, namely the **"Emps"** div, which has "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" by loading the content of **Personal.html**, using jquery.

The steps is:
In MainScreen.html, click the "?EmployeInformation", then click "?QQQQ" link.

**MainScreen.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="./MainScreen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="./Jquery/dev/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="./MainScreen.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="AccountHeader">
            CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
            <br>
            CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
        </div>
        <div id = "HeaderImage">
            <img src="./Images/header.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="MenuList">
            <ul id="NavigationBar">
                <li><button>Notifications</button></li>
                <li><button>File Maintenance</button></li>
                <li><button>Transaction</button></li>
                <li><button>Reports</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="LeftPanel">
            <ul id="FileMaintenanceMenu">
                <li><a href="#">?Authorized Overtime Schedule</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Bank</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Calendar of Length of Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Degree</a></li>
                <li><a id = "link" href="#">?EmployeeInformation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Employees with Evening Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Employees with Extra Load</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Function</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Honorarium of Coaches</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Mode of Salary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Non-Working and Special Holiday</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Parameter File</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Part-time Employees</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Plantilla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Position</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Public Holiday</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Salary Schedule</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Special Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Status of Employment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Student Assistant</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Titles/ Designation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?User/ Password Maintenance</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">?Withholding Tax Table</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            <br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </div>
        <div id="RightPanel">
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            <br>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**MainScreen.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    

    $("#link").click(function()
    {
        alert('a');
            $("#RightPanel").load("./FileMaintenance/EmployeeInformation.html"); 
    });
});
```

**EmployeeInformation.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="../Jquery/dev/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="./EmployeeInformation.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id = "BasicInfo" method="post" action="EmployeeInformation.html">
            <span class = "FieldLabels">ID Number</span> <input type="text" id="IdNumber">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="LastName">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="FirstName">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="MiddleName">
            <br>
            <span class = "FieldLabels">Last Name</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class = "FieldLabels">First Name</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class = "FieldLabels">Middle Name</span>

        </form>
        <ul id = "EmployeeInfoTabs">
            <li><a id = "the" href="#" onclick="alert('b')">?QQQQ</a></li>
            <li><button>?Personal</button></li>
            <li><button>?Employment</button></li>
            <li><button>?Payroll Info</button></li>
            <li><button>?Family and Other Info</button></li>
            <li><button>?Previous Employment</button></li>
        </ul>
        <div id= "Emps">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**MainScreen.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#the").click(function()
    {
        alert('c');
            $("#Emps").load("./EmployeeInformation/Personal.html"); 
    });
});
```

**Personal.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="../../Jquery/dev/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id= "aaaaa">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is my mistake?

I also tried going to the "EmployeeInformation.html" manually, it works, it changes the "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" to "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA" but, if I am in the MainScreen.html it doesn't work, WHY?

The steps is MainScreen.html, click the "?EmployeInformation", then click "?QQQQ" link.

By the way, I want to upload a pic directly here, but my reputation point is less than 10 :(

So, here is the link to the pictures:

The directory of the files and folders:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=20796C7633AE90D!233&authkey=!ACNqvIRZeJYPMkE&v=3&ithint=photo%2cJPG

MainScreen.html
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=20796C7633AE90D!235&authkey=!AJrxTsF0sugU-eE&v=3&ithint=photo%2cJPG

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: show some code wat u r trying?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late upload, I thought I already included it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code to see, I'll start with a basic answer.

Assuming you have access to the DIV, here's how to change its contents with jQuery, which you seem to be using:

Here is a div with a unique id:

```
<div id="mydiv">DDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
```

This is the code to change it:

```
$("#mydiv").html("EEEEEEEEEEEEE");
```

You can also use `html()` to get the element's contents.